# PHP to execute PHP on another server and get the result

Tags: php

My shared hosting does not support postgresql php functions, but I need to load some images from postgresql which is hosted remotely on a dedicated server.

Would it be possible to have a PHP script on the server with postgresql and then another PHP script on the shared hosting would call the script on the postgresql server to get the images from the dedicated server to the shared hosting but I don't want the IP or domain of the dedicated server ever to be revealed.

Would this be possible? if so how?

Comment: Yes, just make an HTTP request (or some other type of request) from the one PHP script, to a PHP script on the other server, and have it output what you want.

Comment: Yes, create an API for it. Send the requests server side so the IP/domain won't be revealed to the user.

Comment: Server A can download data from Server B and send that data to its own user.  It's worth noting, of course, that this will double the bandwidth consumption on Server A, and also be considerably slower for the users.  (Every request for an image would involve Server A first downloading the image from Server B and *then* uploading it to the user.)

Comment: don't know the details, but this is possible: you can configure the php app (which located in server allows you to connect to pg) as an api. that would be ideal solution. 

anyway, there is old and ugly curl. call the php script with curl :)

Comment: @DilaraIsmailova curl isn't ugly.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑIt is compared to Guzzle, though. :-p

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I am not actually a fan of php, but yes, as ceejayoz stated, guzzle is more beautiful. it reminds python's requests.

Comment: I'm sure your free host supports MySQL, consider moving your platform to this. The only advantage of PostgreSQL is that its small and light, what makes it a great solution to ship with applications that will run locally on the final user computer, but it doesn't offer any benefit to a proper dedicated web server, that's why its not supported.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑcurl isn't ugly - but you don't need curl for the most applications where it is used. in many cases like - in this one - it's much faster, easier and cleaner to use `file_get_contents()` instead. plus curl is not a standard plugin in every PHP version!

Comment: @low_rents PHP's ability to load files from URLs using its file handling functions such as `file_get_contents()` is considered a bad practice and a security liability, and I'm pretty sure his free host has it disabled.

Comment: @Havenard no, it's not. your information is wrong. `file_get_contents()` is just getting data from a website like a browser would do.

Comment: @low_rents It is, but is the programmer aware of that? Because that can be used for local files too, and thats what it is usually used for. This mixed functionality of file functions is one of the main reasons why thousands of PHP sites are hacked every day. For this reason, the URL support of file manipulation functions can be disabled on `php.ini`, and most free hosts will disable them.

Comment: @low_rents We don't like trolls around here.

Comment: @low_rents Proceeding with this behavior will lead you to learn who "we" are, though it may not be a pleasant finding. Remember this is not Reddit.

Comment: @Havenard ok, sure. all i know is that i don't like people that can't speak for themselves and have to put a "We" in front of every sentence so it makes them feel stronger.

Comment: @low_rents I'm just trying to make the interested parts aware of why using `file_get_contents()` to fetch data from URLs may be not an option in this case, and also explaining why this feature may have been disabled aswell why its a bad practice. Debating that your solution is still superior without providing any information that backs up your claim and acting like a troll is not being constructive.

Comment: @Havenard it's more likely that curl is not enabled. and you have not pointed out a single security issue with `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: @low_rents I could find you a real life example but I'm busy right now. An example where remote code execution is possible is rare, but XSS is very common.

Comment: @Havenard he is accessing his own server with `file_get_contens()` - you got that information, right?

Comment: @low_rents Thats what they all think until they get hacked.

Comment: @Havenard well, when they get hacked it's 99,99999999% not because of the use of `file_get_contents()`

Comment: @low_rents Depends on how its used and how you filter the relation user input has on what `file_get_contents()` is fetching.

Comment: wow, that was a riot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's even much easier with `file_get_contents()`:

```
$img_binary = file_get_contents("https://i.imgur.com/1H9Ht5a.png");
$img_base64 = base64_encode($img_binary);
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $img_base64 . '">';
```

**plus**: it's a standard PHP method where "cURL" might not be activated in every PHP environment.

be careful with the type of your image. replace `data:image/png;` with `data:image/jpeg;` or other image formats accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. However, you need to make a `JSON API`: the server wich serve `postgresql` needs to fetch results from **Database**, then encode it in `json` with `json_encode()` method and return it with `echo`.

Then, you need to make an **HTTP request** from your **shared hosting** using `CURL`, here's an example:

```
function GetContent($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    $ua   = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl ,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}
```

Then, call the function:

```
$sql = json_decode(GetContent('http://urlofyourserver/testJSON.php'));
```

You can now get the result in the `$sql` variable `:)`

Oh and don't forget, make a password request using `$_GET` requests on your server wich serves postgresql, otherwise everyone will be able to access to data if they found your server URL.

> e.g: http://urlofyourserver/testJSON.php?secret=xxx

You can also pass the query as a get parameter, but It can be risked if your password is cracked.

**Postgresql server sample**

```
$realPass = "blablah";
if(isset($_GET['secret'])) {
   $pass = $_GET['secret'];
   if($pass === $realPass) {
     header('Content-type: application/json');
     // do query here and return it as $test var
     echo json_encode($test);

   }
}
```

Comment: or you just use `file_get_contents()`, don't need curl or JSON and have three lines of code (see my answer).

Comment: `JSON` is better for helping him returning every type of data. He can also make other requests than requesting an image. Also, I think that `CURL` has more options. `JSON` can help him in the future for other types of data `;)`
I know you can create a `stream context` with `file_get_contents()`, but `CURL` is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use php curl

Example that will send the get parameters get1 and get2 to a test.php on a server with IP 192.168.2.2

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://192.168.2.2/test.php?get1=value&get2=value2',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)'
));

// Send the request & save response
// The response could be JSON with the results from the database
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

You could use PHP to encode and decode your results in JSON to make things easier. To do this use json_encode() and json_decode()

If you want some more information check out:

- http://codular.com/curl-with-php
- http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with another idea that is much better imho; it also might be better in terms of security.

use a PHP script that simulates being an image file:

```
// example code for getting binary image data from db 
// (PDO and MySQL in this example)

$stmt = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT image_bin FROM image_table WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1" );
$stmt->bindValue(":id", $_GET["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$image_bin = $stmt->fetchColumn();

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $image_bin;
```

on the page where you want to show the image you don't even need to use PHP:

```
<img src="http://myimageserver.com/image.php?id=3425">
```

in this example you just need to use the GET variable `id` to define/decide which image is shown. most of the work is done on the remote server where you could grab the desired image by using POSTGRESQL like you mentioned.